# How to get sitelinks to appear on Google Search?

Tags: google-search

How do get my sitelinks to appear on Google search results?

[image: Google sitelinks]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Answer (score 6):

Per your picture, you are referring to sitelinks and not sitemaps in the Google jargon. Here is what Google Webmaster site has to say about sitelinks:

> Google has not generated any sitelinks for your site. Sitelinks are completely automated, and we show them only if we think they'll be useful to the user. If your site's structure doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks are relevant to the user's query, we won't show them. However, we are always working to improve how we find and display sitelinks.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing are "sitelinks" which aren't generated from your sitemap. Google [don't give details](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=28082&topic=8994) of where these links come from, but they appear to be related to things like a [clear navigation structure](http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/sitelinks.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this. Google decides whether to show [sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334) or not.

Answer (score 1):

that's not a sitemap, it's sitelinks. Even after you get your site into google, sitemap or otherwise, you won't get site links unless they deem that it's appropriate for your site. Google webmaster tools is a good place to start, but don't expect site links any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can get sitelinks in Google's search results, but takes time. Suppose if you want to get your product page under site links, you need to promote it and see that you get lot of hits to it, the page should be user and search engine friendly. It should appears on top pages with your target keywords. Now its up to you how you promote it online, once you get good hits to the page with top ranking you can get the results in couple of months.

What ever I suggest above as per my experience, you can try but I can't guarantee it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Sitelinks can not be manually generated. Google will decide the popular pages of your website and start showing in search results. So if you want to show your sitelinks in search results, you should start working on the following things:

- Use a Clear Website Structure and Navigation
- Use Relevant Page Titles
- Add an XML Sitemap to
- Google Search Console Build Internal Links Use Relevant Page Titles
- Increase Brand Awareness (Guest blogging on popular industry sites,
  Giving interviews, Reaching out to online news outlets, Getting
  positive reviews and testimonials, Participating in online community
  discussions)
- Build Internal Links